# Handling images using apache server

Tags: image, apache, image-processing, imdb

May be the heading of this question is wrong, but here in this section where i can explain my question properly.

Below mentioned link is a image of movie(ZD30) hosted by IMDB website.

[imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTcyODUwODY5NV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwMDY4NTE4OA@@.*V1*.jpg](http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTcyODUwODY5NV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwMDY4NTE4OA@@._V1_.jpg)

But when u change the the link to this

http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTcyODUwODY5NV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwMDY4NTE4OA@@._V1._SX200_CR0,0,0,0_.jpg

results me the same image but in a different width and less size.
I am highly impressed by this technique and want's to implement in my website too.

Any help will be appreciated.

thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can maintain your own Image server, and check the request eg.

?URL=ABC_20x20.jpg

process the image at your end and response the client by changes one.